# Conversion error with read_excel for dtype=str using pandas, python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am reading an excel file using pandas in python and it works for some files and for some others it throws the following error "Unable to convert column DESCRIPTION to type " where DESCRIPTION is one of the many columns of the excel. I cannot see any difference between the excels for which it works for the ones it doesn't.

when I read it without dtype=str, it works just fine, but I need to read it as a string.

```
df = pandas.read_excel(fileFullPath, dtype=str)
```

Any help with this error solving this error will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

From the `pandas` [documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html?highlight=read_excel#pandas.read_excel):

> Data type for data or columns. E.g. {‘a’: np.float64, ‘b’: np.int32}
>   Use object to preserve data as stored in Excel and not interpret
>   dtype. If converters are specified, they will be applied INSTEAD of
>   dtype conversion.

if you only want to convert one specific column into a string, give `dtype` a `dictionary` like so.

```
data_dtypes = {
    'description': 'str'
}

df = pandas.read_excel(fileFullPath, dtype=data_dtypes)
```